# Read more files and find max occurence

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, find-occurrences

I have 4 files .txt in my directory.
My objective is:

1) run a code that find max occurrence

2) take the execution time for each file

3) save execution times in a csv file

4) print an average of the execution times

I've done this:

---

```
import timeit

text = open('testoprova.txt','r')
testo = str(text.read()).lower()

dizionario = dict()

for parole in testo.split():
    dizionario[parole] = dizionario.get(parole, 0) + 1

maxcount = max(zip(dizionario.values(), dizionario.keys()))
print(maxcount, "Tempo esecuzione:", timeit.timeit())

#____________________________________________________________________________________

text1 = open('testoprovadue.txt','r')
testo2 = str(text1.read()).lower()

dizionario = dict()

for parole in testo2.split():
    dizionario[parole] = dizionario.get(parole, 0) + 1

maxcount2 = max(zip(dizionario.values(), dizionario.keys()))
print(maxcount2, "Tempo esecuzione:", timeit.timeit())

#_____________________________________________________________________________________

text3 = open('testoprovatre.txt','r')
testo3 = str(text3.read()).lower()

dizionario = dict()

for parole in testo3.split():
    dizionario[parole] = dizionario.get(parole, 0) + 1

maxcount3 = max(zip(dizionario.values(), dizionario.keys()))
print(maxcount3, "Tempo esecuzione:", timeit.timeit())

#_____________________________________________________________________________________

text4 = open('testoprova4.txt','r')
testo4 = str(text4.read()).lower()

dizionario = dict()

for parole in testo4.split():
    dizionario[parole] = dizionario.get(parole, 0) + 1

maxcount4 = max(zip(dizionario.values(), dizionario.keys()))
print(maxcount4, "Tempo esecuzione:", timeit.timeit())
_____________________________________________________________
```

---

But I get this error message:

```
(4, 'ciao') Tempo esecuzione: 0.042456
(4, 'il') Tempo esecuzione: 0.036894399999999994
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/petti/PycharmProjects/untitled/Primo.py", line 37, in <module>
    maxcount3 = max(zip(dizionario.values(), dizionario.keys()))
**ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence**
```

Why?

Comment: Hi, the error says that the arguments of the `max` function are empty, so in your code, are you sure that `testo3` (and thus `testoprovatre.txt`) is not empty?

Comment: Add an if statement to check that you are actually sending a value to "max()".

if zip(dizionario.values(), dizionario.keys()) is None:
    maxcount3 = max(zip(dizionario.values(), dizionario.keys()))
else:
    pass